# Launch activity silent

Tags: android, android-activity

We have an activity for splash screen that launches main app activity after initialization.
However, if user presses Home button on splash screen activity, home screen appears, but after few moments main activity launches.

Is there are way not to bring launching activity to foreground? Main app activity shouldn't shows after home button pressed, but if user returns to application via long pressing on home, he expect to see main activity, not splash screen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If splash screen is an activity then call `finish()` on this activity after certain time of visibility and then in its `onStop()` method launch your main activity. By doing this, when finished is called on your splash screen, it will be out from activity stack and the user will always return to main activity if resume from pressing home-key long or selected from launcher

Comment: Splash screen activity should be finished only after initialization completed. Also, in that case main app activity would be appeared on home button pressed instead of home screen

Comment: fine, then simply call **finish()** on splash screen when initialization of main activity is done

Comment: Okay. When to launch main activity? If we launch it directly after initialization, it will popped up if splash already in background. That's not good.

Comment: launch your main activity in splash screen's **onStop()** method. So when **finish()** is called on splash screen, it will call **onPause()**, **onStop()** and **onDestroy()** respectively.

Comment: In that case main app activity may be launched before initialization completes and on pressing home button main activity will be appeared instead of hiding application.

Comment: then i guess it would be reasonable to set some boolean flags to check when initialization is done